# Is typed text stored somewhere?

Tags: privacy

All the things we type (like usernames, passwords, text in a text file etc.) are saved somewhere in some log files? If yes, formatting and initializing the drive, will delete them?

I am asking because I am going to sell my pc for the first time to someone I don't know ...

Comment: Remove or replace the original HD.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should **always** completely destroy all data before selling your computer.

One way to do this is by using [DBAN](https://dban.org/), which is a live operating system, designed to shred all data.

Comment: Beware, before destroying the OS from the main disk, it could be useful to first make sure to be able re-install it. It does not matter for free OS like Linux or xxBSD, but it can matter for Windows... At least control whether the license key is available or whether the re-install partition is still there and still useable...